# asp.net mvc 4 controller routing depending on url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, controller, routes

Depending on url, I want to route different controllers. So depending on different URLs directed to same DNS server, I want to give my website a different look and feel.

To test this locally I tried:

```
public class RouteConfig
{ 
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "localhost",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", id = UrlParameter.Optional }    
        );
    }
}
```

Wat I wanted was the Contact page to appear, not the default Home Page as the URL was `:/localhost:portnr./`.

How can I get the first bit of an URL (domain) to decide which controller to route?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the **Contact** controller and **Index** Action, and you want to load that on page load,
 you can specify as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```